# Is there an axiomatic theory for numerical methods?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, solution-verification, formal-languages

Is there a formal language (an axiomatic system and the corresponding logic) that makes it possible to reason about numerical solutions of differential equations?

In other words, is there a formal system that can be used to prove that a given method for numerical solution of differential equation generates a solution with a given accuracy and that it converge.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's going to be one overarching theory that works for all differential equations. The behavior of ODEs varies wildly. There's a reason that numerical analysis (which focuses heavily on ODEs and stability of numerical solutions) is its own field..

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you could like to read the chapter 8 of the book The Mathematics of Diffusion of Crank.

Comment: Results in numerical methods are rigorous theorems of ZFC of course, so I think you need to narrow what you mean by "axiomatic theory."

Comment: @NoahSchweber, ZFC would be of course an "axiomatic theory". The only question is if numerical methods for solving differential equations are already formulated in terms of ZFC. As far as I understand one first would need to formulate relevant concepts in terms of ZFC (provide all needed definitions). Is it already done?